# endless runner game like dino rush object placement in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My game is mostly already completed, but I need some changes related to the placement of objects. I have the same objects like the dinorush game. Like (fruit, block, missile, ball etc). I need proper placement of all objects like in the dino rush game. Currenly I am using random positions and movement of objects. I have not used any physics in my game. Also if I design placement using a tile map, then can we have magnet effects when my player stands near to the banana object? (I mean all banana automatically are attracted by the player)
Please help me. I am newbie in cocosd. This is my first game in cocos2d.

Comment: if u found solution then let me know

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are exactly needing to know? What changes do you need to make related to the objects' placement?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new class inherited the ccNode named magnet(banana) then add it to your game.Calculate the distance between the player and the banana.If the distance is less than the number you want, then move it to the player.

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    float distance = ccpDistance(self.position, player.position);
    if(distance < d){
        CCAction *action =  [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:player.position];
        [self addChild:action];
    }
}
```